# Rails will not start on OS X 10.8.3 with 'too short escaped multibyte character' using Ruby 2.0.0-p0 and Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've installed Ruby using the standard RVM and homebrew setup.  I tried installing a new version of readline, then force reinstalling ruby-2.0.0, but that didn't solve this.  The only other similar errors I can find by searching are in loofah, but that doesn't help me since I can't modify the html5 gem similarly.  Has anyone else encountered this when upgrading to Ruby 2?

```
/Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/html5-0.10.0/lib/html5/inputstream.rb:305: too short escaped multibyte character: /^ (SyntaxError)
                ( [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
                |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
                | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
                |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
                |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
                | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
                |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
                )/x
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/html5-0.10.0/lib/html5/tokenizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/html5-0.10.0/lib/html5/html5parser.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/html5-0.10.0/lib/html5.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/xss_terminate-0.2/lib/xss_terminate.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/git/forks/shoptap-server/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/jday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Looks like this isn't exclusive to OS X, either, just deployed to Heroku and it's crashing in the exact same spot.

Answer (score 0):

All right, turns out if I'd actually read the error message I would've realized this is a syntax error in the html5 gem, which is a dependency of xss_terminate. Replacing xss_terminate with loofah-activerecord (see xss_foliate) fixed the issue.